# Candidate with Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that when a candidate comes to interview for a job, the probability that after the interview, he will want the job is $P(A)=0.68$. Also, the probability that after the interview, they want him as a candidate is $P(B)=0.36$.  The probability $P(A/B)=0.88$.  What is $P(A \text{ and } B)$?

Comment: Hello.  Do you know the definition P(A|B)?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level.

Comment: Do you really mean $P\left(A/B\right)$ or is it $P\left(A\mid B\right)$? There is an essential difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard application of an [axiom of probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability):

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) = 0.88 \cdot 0.36 = 0.3168.$$